# Как совместить паттерн "Стратегия" и "Фабричный метод"?

Tags: ооп, абстрактная-фабрика, шаблон-стратегия, шаблоны-проектирования

При проектировании столкнулся с задачей: создаются разные обьекты, с помощью фабричного метода. Каждый обьект может производить определённые действия, некоторые типы обьектов могут производить одно и то же действие.
Вопрос заключается в том, как прикрутить тут паттерн стратегии так, чтобы обьект производил только действия, свойственные ему. Нужно создавать интерфейсы под каждую категорию действий?

Comment: какой-нибудь пример с конкретикой вопросу не помешал бы...

Comment: Фабричный метод - порождающий шаблон. Стратегия - поведенческий шаблон. Первый создаёт объекты. Второй - задаёт алгоритм/поведение объектов. Они лежать в разных плоскостях. Но, да, их можно совместить, как и любые другие паттерны.

Answer (score 0):

Да, для стратегии придется создавать абстракции.

Скажем есть фабрика создающая какие-то списки.

List Factory.create()

Так вот стратегия будет реализация интерфейса List это ArrayList или LinkedList.